# JPA Cascade Delete with ManyToOne without OneToMany

Tags: java, jpa, cascade, cascading-deletes

I have the following structure of objects:

```
public class Entity1 {  

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<Entity2> listOfEntitys;
    ... 
}

public class Entity2 {  

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<Entity3> listOfEntitys;
    ... 
}

public class Entity3 {  
    ...
}

//Here it can be thousand of it for one entity3
public class Entity4 {  

    @ManyToOne
    private Entity3 entity;
        ... 
}
```

Now, I want delete `Entity1` and all entities should delete on cascade, too. 
The Problem is,... how can I delete all `entitys4` on cascade?

I have tried 2 solutions:

- I add a list on entity3 and delete it on cascade.
- I make two querys: first I select all `entitys3` that could be in `entity1` -> `entity2` than I delete all `entitys4` with it. After it I can delete `entity1/2/3` normally per cascade because the entity reference from `4` to `3` is erased.

Give it another solution? Which solution should I prefer?

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the first solution but slightly modified:

```
@Entity
public class Entity1 {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entity1", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Entity2> listofentitys;
}

@Entity
public class Entity2 {
    @ManyToOne
    private Entity1 entity1;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entity2", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Entity3> listofentitys;
}

@Entity
public class Entity3 {
    @ManyToOne
    private Entity2 entity2;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="entity3", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Entity4> listofentitys;
}

@Entity
public class Entity4 {
    @ManyToOne
    private Entity3 entity3;
}
```

By introducing bidirectional relationships between the entities you can avoid join tables thus improving overall performance while exchanging data with the underlying database. Such approach seems more reasonable to me than the second one as JPA implicitly takes care of everything.

Removing entity may look as follows:

```
public <T> void remove(Class<T> clazz, int id) {
    T entity = em.find(clazz, id);
    if (entity != null) {
        em.remove(entity);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: thank for help. But i changed the structure and delete it with jpql. Thats the way, that should i prefer to bulk deletes.